# How can I convert a timestamp string of the form "%d%H%MZ" to a datetime object?

Tags: python, string, datetime, converters

I have timestamp strings of the form "091250Z", where the first two numbers are the date and the last four numbers are the hours and minutes. The "Z" indicates UTC. Assuming the timestamp corresponds to the current month and year, how can this string be converted reliably to a datetime object?

I have the parsing to a timedelta sorted, but the task quickly becomes nontrivial when going further and I'm not sure how to proceed:

```
datetime.strptime("091250Z", "%d%H%MZ")
```

Comment: In most languages DateTime objects have functions to add months,days,hours, etc sepperatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to `replace` the `year` and `month` of your existing datetime object.

```
your_datetime_obj = datetime.strptime("091250Z", "%d%H%MZ")
new_datetime_obj = your_datetime_obj.replace(year=datetime.now().year, month=datetime.now().month)
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer]. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5244995)

Answer (score 0):

Like this? You've basically already done it, you just needed to assign it a variable

```
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.strptime('091250Z', '%m%H%MZ')
```

Comment: Thanks, but see the problem is that `datetime.strptime('091250Z', '%d%H%MZ')` gives `datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 9, 12, 50)` when it needs to get the *current* year and month: `datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 9, 12, 50)`.